# How to create an RDD with the whole content of files as values?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a directory with many files, and I want to create a RDD whose value is the content of each file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SparkContext.wholeTextFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) method that reads:

> a directory of text files from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI. Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.

Just keep in mind that individual files have to fit into worker memory and generally speaking it is less efficient than using `textFile`.